# Proteus/Ares - how to scrap old layout but keep Isis schematic

Tags: pcb, layout, proteus

I have got in a mess on the layout. I want to scrap the existing layout and restart with a new board size. How do I do that without restarting the entire project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you refer to version 8 where the schematic file (.dsn) and board file (.lyt) are stored in a single project file (.pdsprj).
The simplest way I can think of is to create a copy of the project (as a backup), and then in ARES use the selection mode (arrow icon in the top of the left side menu) to select the entire board and click delete. Then you can start the board from scratch.
You can also delete selectively only the tracks (keeping the component placement) using the track mode.

Comment: Yes, v8. Thanks. Unless someone has a better answer, I'll flag yours as it.